# how can i shuffles 7-digit number randomly in java

Tags: javascript, java

like this :

Sample run:
Please enter a number:  1234567
The shuffled number is: 4356271
Sample run:
Please enter a number:  1000001
The shuffled number is: 0100100

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: While I agree with the close, I disagree with the duplicate question.

Comment: @AntonH See the list of dupes now. I can add JavaScript if needed

Answer (score -1):

Converting the number in a String use this method passing the string to it!

```
public void shuffle(String input){
        List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for(char c:input.toCharArray()){
            characters.add(c);
        }
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(input.length());
        while(characters.size()!=0){
            int randPicker = (int)(Math.random()*characters.size());
            output.append(characters.remove(randPicker));
        }
        System.out.println(output.toString());
    }
```

Comment: How do you prompt for the number and who says OP actually MEANT JAVA

Comment: NOTE : I want to shuffle integer not arrays

Comment: you can convert an integer to String, pass it to this method and transform the returned string to integer again....